# Get Value of text inside label Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I looked around for an answer to this but have been unsuccessful so far. What I have is a div containing radio buttons with titles

```
<div>
  <label title_id="1" function="update_answer_title" class="pure-radio" for="option-1">
      <input type="radio" name="1" value="1" id="option-1">
      Talking on the phone or sending a text message.
 </label>
 <label title_id="2" function="update_answer_title" class="pure-radio" for="option-2">
      <input type="radio" name="1" value="2" id="option-2">
      Having your keys held in your hand, ready to unlock car and/or provide defense.
 </label>
</div>
```

Now what I am trying to do is get the text inside a label when that label is clicked. Not the html of the radio button.  So inside my onclick listener I am What I have tried so far is:

```
     evt.target.childNodes[1].valueOf().innerText
     evt.target.childNodes[1].toString()
     JSON.stringify(evt.target.childNodes[1])
```

And a bunch of other permutations of these attempts. but each time all I get from that value that these are returning is:

```
[object Text]
```

How do I convert object Text to normal text?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, That was silly, I figured it out, instead of doing

```
evt.target.childNodes[1] ...
```

All I needed to do was get the inner text of the target and that will filter out the html for me automagically so the solution is:

```
evt.target.innerText
```

EDIT:

In Response to comments, innerText does not exist in Firefox. So the way to do this is really: evt.target.innerText || evt.target.textContent;

Thank you @Ruslan Osmanov

Comment: use `evt.target.textContent || evt.target.innerText` for compatibility

Comment: That's right. `innerText` is not standard, and Firefox doesn't have it.

Comment: Firefox has `innerText` implemented since version 45! It will be probably be safe to drop out `textContent` after a few more releases.